# box2d (andengine gles2) PhysicsConnector syntax error

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, physics

i have applied the gravity on my ball that is dynamic cirle body. when it reaches at the bottom of the screen it goes out of the screen. wo i want to make boundaries of my physics world.

i created 4 lines and 4 linebodies respectively. but when i try to register physics connector, it works fine for my box bodies and sprites but not for my linebodies :(

### code:

```
Line line_top = new Line(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 0, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    Line line_left = new Line(0, 0, 0, CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    Line line_right = new Line(CAMERA_WIDTH, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    Line line_bottom = new Line(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    line_top.setColor(1, 1, 1); // RGB
    line_left.setColor(1, 1, 1);
    line_right.setColor(1, 1, 1);
    line_bottom.setColor(1, 1, 1);

    Body wall_top = PhysicsFactory.createLineBody(mPhysicsWorld, line_top, FIXTURE_DEF);
    Body wall_left = PhysicsFactory.createLineBody(mPhysicsWorld, line_left, FIXTURE_DEF);
    Body wall_right = PhysicsFactory.createLineBody(mPhysicsWorld, line_right, FIXTURE_DEF);
    Body wall_bottom = PhysicsFactory.createLineBody(mPhysicsWorld, line_bottom, FIXTURE_DEF);
```

this works fine for me

```
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(playButtonSprite, BoxBody2, true, true));
```

but when i pass my line as argument

```
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(line_top, BoxBody, true, true));
```

it shows this error

```
The constructor PhysicsConnector(Line, Body, boolean, boolean) is undefined
```

Comment: Try change you lines class from Line to Shape: `Shape line_top = new Line(...);`

Comment: doen't work ! it accepts IAreaShape object. :(

Comment: Should your line register physics connector not be:

    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(line_top, wall_top, true, true));

(Second argument of new physics connecter - wall_top)?

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar in my game (Screen boundaries as physics objects). Apparently, I had this problem too, with the `PhysicsConnector` not accepting `Line` - so I used `Rectangle` instead. You can create a rectangle with a width of 1, For example, the equivalent rectangle to `line_top` will be:

```
Rectangle rect_top = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 1);
```